# Different Manifest files when having a cached web app?

Tags: html, caching

I've just started reading the explanation of the HTML 5 cache in w3schools and there is some confusion in my head regarding this.

consider having this manifest file:

```
  CACHE MANIFEST
    /main.html
    /logic.js
```

This file will load these two files. My question is what will happen when you have this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
        /main.html
```

And you load `logic.js` in the `main.html`. Will it still work?